# How can I fourier transform this equation using pairs?

Tags: fourier-transform

Fourier Transform Pairs:

[image]

The above is all the fourier transform pairs that I've been given and my equation is this:

[image]

How can I fourier transform this above equation using the pairs given to me?

I tried to find one that looks similar but none of them seem to match the format, is it possible to do?

The closest one looks like the fourth one from the top on the left, but the T doesn't match so I don't think it can be used.

Comment: What is $U(t)$?

Comment: You should also know how to find the FT of a nonzero scalar times a function.  You'll need that for this exercise.

Comment: @avs U(t) is the heaviside step function

Comment: @BrianBorchers not entirely sure what you mean by that, the only other thing given to me on the data sheet related to FT's are the symmetry properties: `f(t)<->F(w)=>f(-t)<->F(-w)=F*(w) for real f(t)`

Comment: @BrianBorchers oh you're talking about the scaling theorem yes? That is: `f(at) <-> 1/|a| F(w/a)`

Comment: $R(t) = 10^{-4} [ U(t) \exp( -t / 10^{3}) + (1 - U(t)) \exp( t / 10^{3}) ]$

Comment: @Aequitas, Brian was referring to the fact that the Fourier transform is a linear transformation.  But, you are right, you will need the argument rescaling property that you cited, as well.

Comment: @avs what is that equation?

Comment: Linearity here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties

Comment: Linearity and one formula from the table are all that you need.